# Getting BadRequest response in post to sharepoint trying to create a folder

Tags: .net, sharepoint, .net-6.0, restsharp

I a currently building a console application in net6 in order to create folders and files in my organization sharepoint site.

I am using RestSharp and i getting bad request response in post request to create a folder with the following error: "The property '__metadata' does not exist on type 'SP.Folder'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type".

In my research I have found that the possible cause of the bad request is that it is necessary to indicate the "application/json;odata=verbose" header. But i am spicifing this header in my request in both headers "Accept" and "Content-Type", but keep getting error.

This is my code:

```
var request = new RestRequest
{
    Resource = $"{RESOURCE}/_api/web/folders",
    Method = Method.Post
 };

 request.AddHeaders(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
 {
     new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Authorization", $"Bearer {_accessToken}"),
     new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose"),
     new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose")
 });

 request.AddJsonBody(new
 {
     __metadata = new
     {
         type = "SP.Folder"
     },
     ServerRelativeUrl = $"ContainedFolder/{FolderName}"
 });

 var response = await _client.ExecuteAsync(request);

 if (response == null || response.StatusCode != expectedStatus)
            throw new Exception($"Unable to create folder. StatusCode: {response?.StatusCode}. Error: {response?.ErrorMessage}. RawContent: {response?.Content}");

 return response;
```

Comment: I tried the same request on postman and works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify `Content-Type` header in `AddJsonBody`. The second parameter is `contentType` with default value `application/json`. Looks like it overrides `Content-Type` header specified in `AddHeaders`

```
request.AddHeaders(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
 {
     new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Authorization", $"Bearer {_accessToken}"),
     new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose")
 });

 request.AddJsonBody(new
 {
     __metadata = new
     {
         type = "SP.Folder"
     },
     ServerRelativeUrl = $"ContainedFolder/{FolderName}"
 }, "application/json;odata=verbose");
```